# C: How to kill a process on another machine through SSH?

Tags: c, ssh

I am looking to run a program written in `C` on my machine and have it SSH into another machine to kill a program running on it.

Inside my program, I have attempted:

```
system("ssh username@machine.com && pkill sleep && exit");
```

which will cause my terminal to SSH into the remote machine, but it ends there.  I have also tried:

```
execl("ssh","ssh","username@machine.com",NULL);
execl("pkill","pkill","sleep",NULL);
execl("exit","exit",NULL);
```

but it will not kill my dummy `sleep` process I have running.

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my process.

Comment: I don't think you can do that, and why would you want to?

Comment: Creating a program which replicates the `who` command.  Required to run a process on each machine on the network, and implement a bully algorithm to keep track of who is the main machine.  Need to be able to kill the process on each machine as well, which is what I am implementing first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second example won't do what you want as it will execute each `execl` on the local machine. IE it will

- Execute `ssh usrname@machine.com`
- Execute `pkill`
- Execute `exit`

But, actually, unless you are surrounding these by `fork`, the first `execl` if it succeeds in running at all will replace the current process, meaning the second and third ones never get called.

So, let's work out why the first (more hopeful) example doesn't work.

This should do the equivalent of:

```
/bin/sh -c 'ssh username@machine.com && pkill sleep && exit'
```

The `&& exit` is superfluous. And you want the `pkill` to run on the remote machine. Therefore you want something that does:

```
/bin/sh -c 'ssh username@machine.com pkill sleep'
```

(note the absence of `&&` so the `pkill` is run on the remote machine).

That means you want:

```
system("ssh username@machine.com pkill sleep");
```

If that doesn't work, check the command starting `/bin/sh -c` above works. Does `ssh` ask for a password, for instance? If so, it won't work. You will need to use a public key.

Comment: I was suspecting that but I didn't rememebr if `ssh` did execute commands that way. Now I do remembe, i have used it before, not from a c program of course.

Comment: Well that did the trick!  I was assuming that I would have to close each SSH connection before starting another one, which threw me off.  Also, I was under the impression that executing multiple commands on one line required a `;` or `&&`, but apparently not in this case.  Thanks!

Comment: A question: When you say that `execl` will replace the current process (when there is no forking), that means the program which executed `execl` will stop running at that very moment?

Comment: Yes, if the `execl` succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

one can always run, over ssh, the command:

```
kill $(pgrep -o -f 'command optional other stuff')
```

Get your remote process to handle SIGTERM, where it can do its cleanup's. (including killing any processes its started)

Google 'man pgrep' to see what the -o and -f do. -f is important to correctly target the signal.
the 'pgrep' returns the pid with trailing \n but this does not need to be stripped off before passing it to 'kill'.
Yours
Allan